# Difference between a maven property that is a "user property" for a plugin's parameter and a property that is a "default" for the same parameter

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Several maven plugins have ["encoding" parameter](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#encoding) that has a property associated with it and also has a default value that is also a property.

```
<encoding>
User Property: encoding
Default: ${project.build.sourceEncoding}
```

It appears that these two properties do the same thing:

```
<properties>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Is there a reason for this redundancy?
Is there a difference between a property that is a "user property" for a plugin's parameter and a property that is a "default" for the same parameter?

Comment: A user property means you can use it on command line like `mvn -Dencoding=XXX` the default value is picked up when the appropriate definition is given via `project.build.sourceEncoding` etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise project.build.sourceEncoding can also be set in the command line. What's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

The two are not equivalent.

- `project.build.sourceEncoding` refers to the encoding of all source files. That includes resources.
- `encoding` is specific to the encoding of Java source files.

Comment: Is this because the "encoding" parameter of the Resources Plugin does not use `encoding` property? Also, why does it define `project.build.sourceEncoding` as "default" instead of "user property"?

Comment: The `encoding` parameter of the Resources Plugin actually *defaults* to the value of the `project.build.sourceEncoding`. I guess the name `sourceEncoding` is really misleading.

Comment: I believe that a look at the source code of the Maven plugins would make it clear. Here's one for the resources plugin: https://github.com/apache/maven-resources-plugin/blob/maven-resources-plugin-3.1.0/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/resources/ResourcesMojo.java#L69

Comment: What would be the difference between:
`@Parameter( property = "foo")`
and
`@Parameter( defaultValue = "${foo}" )` ?